# nodejs server starts before file is ready

Tags: node.js

It reads the csv file, and I convert it to json. The problem is that the server starts before it creates the json file, so it doesn't send anything.

I have a csv file here:

```
25.07.2014 02:05:00.000,1.34650,1.34655,1.34650,1.34654,22.44,
25.07.2014 02:06:00.000,1.34654,1.34654,1.34651,1.34652,7.69,
25.07.2014 02:07:00.000,1.34652,1.34652,1.34646,1.34650,18.85,
25.07.2014 02:08:00.000,1.34652,1.34652,1.34650,1.34650,18.40,
25.07.2014 02:09:00.000,1.34652,1.34652,1.34650,1.34650,32.36,
25.07.2014 02:10:00.000,1.34650,1.34652,1.34650,1.34651,8.97,
```

([Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/s3N61Y4n))

And a nodejs server code here:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileName = "test.csv";
var fileToArray = [];
var fileToJson;
fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
  if (exists) {
    fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
      fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
          var data = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length);
          var lines = data.split("\r\n");
          var fileColCount = 6;
          var lineInArray = [];
          lines.forEach(function(line) {
            lineInArray = line.split(',');
            lineInArray.pop();
            fileToArray.push(lineInArray);
          })
          console.log(fileToArray);
          console.log('***********');
          fileToJson = JSON.stringify(fileToArray);
          console.log(fileToJson);
          fs.close(fd);
        });
      });
    });
  }
});

var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io = socketio.listen(3636);


if (fileToJson) { // Empty?
  console.log(fileToJson);
} else {
  console.log('fileToJson empty !!!');
}
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress
  console.log('Connection ip address: ' + clientIp);

  socket.emit('candles', {
    'jsoncandles': fileToJson
  });

  //send data to client
  setInterval(function() {
    socket.emit('date', {
      'date': new Date()
    });
  }, 1000);

  //recieve client data
  socket.on('client_data', function(data) {
    process.stdout.write(data.letter);
  });

});
```

([Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/45YNRjMj))

Any ideas?

Comment: Try watching for file create event: https://coderwall.com/p/x41dga

Comment: There was a comment here mention synchronous file reading, which I believe is the correct solution. You can replace all of your fs calls with their corresponding `Sync` versions, [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). Notably, `fs.readFileSync()`. I also don't think you need to do all the nesting with `exists`, `stat`, etc... Just open it and check the `err` object in the callback. I assume the file exists at the start and is on the server?

Comment: I have solved the problem, it's not the best solution, but it works. Link: http://pastebin.com/HNP7jbcj